# My html isn't validating

Tags: html

I can't figure out what to do for my error in my html.

```
<link href="final project.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

for my external css it says:

"Bad value final project.css for attribute href on element link: Whitespace in path component. Use %20 in place of spaces."

Comment: Hmm, "Use %20 in place of spaces" seems fairly useful.

Answer (score 3):

To validate, you will need to encode the space in your file name using `%20` in place of the `' '` character.

```
<link href="final%20project.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Answer (score 1):

You have already answered your question....
Try this and see if it works for you

```
<link href="final%20project.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead:

```
<link href="final%20project.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

You can't have an explicit space in an `href` target name. Spaces must be encoded using HTML hex format (in this case, hex `20` is a space, which is `%20` in HTML hex format).